# Book with id:2 is not found - @InjectMocks is not working - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test BookService class and in that class method `findBookById()`

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class BookServiceTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    BookService bookService;
    
    @Mock
    BookRepository bookRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private BookDto bookDto = new BookDto();
    private Book book = new Book();
    private Book book1 = new Book();
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<BookDto> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Test
    void findBookById() {
    book.setId(2L);
    book.setTitle("Harry Potter");
    book.setAuthor("J. K. Rowling");
    book.setPublisher("Bloomsbury Publishing");
    book.setCategory(Category.CLASSIC);
    book.setTotalCount(10);
    book.setRented(0);
    
    bookDto = bookService.findBookById(2L);
         Mockito.when(bookRepository.findById(2L)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(book));
assertNotNull(bookDto);
assertEquals("Harry Potter", bookDto.getTitle());
assertEquals(book, bookService.findBookById(2L));
        }
```

From this code I am getting an error

`com.example.library.exception.BookNotFoundException: Book with id:2 is not found.`

**UPDATE**

When I try to do `assertEquals(book, bookService.findBookById(2L));`

I am getting following error:

`org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:  Expected :Book(id=2, title=Harry Potter, author=J. K. Rowling, publisher=Bloomsbury Publishing, category=CLASSIC, totalCount=10, rented=0) Actual   :BookDto(id=2, title=Harry Potter, author=J. K. Rowling, publisher=Bloomsbury Publishing, category=CLASSIC, totalCount=10, rented=0)`

Which I believe its coming from wrong injection of `bookService`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense. Why run it with Spring when you only want Mockito.

Comment: I edited it my bad.

Comment: Please add a definition of the object under test (BookService)  and also exclude spring boot from the tags in the question.

Comment: You should first register behavior then call the method, you are doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first call `bookService.findBookById(2L)` and then stub `bookRepository.findById(2L)`. Stubbing must go first, before calling method under test.

```
Mockito.when(bookRepository.findById(2L)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(book));
var bookDto = bookService.findBookById(2L);
assertNotNull(bookDto);
assertEquals("Harry Potter", bookDto.getTitle());
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I did change that part and it works but then when I add `assertEquals(book, bookService.findBookById(2L));` I am getting following error `Expected :Book(id=2, title=Harry Potter, author=J. K. Rowling, publisher=Bloomsbury Publishing, category=CLASSIC, totalCount=10, rented=0)
Actual   :BookDto(id=2, title=Harry Potter, author=J. K. Rowling, publisher=Bloomsbury Publishing, category=CLASSIC, totalCount=10, rented=0)` I updeted my question as well so you can check it :)

Comment: The types do not match: book Vs bookDto. The service returns bookDto, doesn't it? In your test, you must compare with expected bookDto.

Comment: Yes, it returns bookDto.

Comment: As a side note - if BookDto is a simple wrapper around Book, the transformation is typically done at the Controller level. (If it combines data from multiple repos / has non-trivial transformation of Book involving business logic, Service level is OK). But to my eyes (from error message you posted) both have same fields. If this is the case, get rid of BookDto

Comment: Yes it combines data from multiple repos. As I am new with unit testing it's hard for me to get going with testing DTO's conversions. I am pretty stuck. Is it better if I mocked classes `Book.class` and `BookDto.class`? I didn't find any article explaining it well.

Comment: For model or dto objects, go with real objects - they are easy to construct. You mock services, especially the ones that have methods with side effects undesired in unit tests (long calls, calls to external servers are frequent examples)